# Python circular references

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, circular-dependency

trying to have two class that reference each others, in the same file. What would be the best way to have this working:

```
class Foo(object):
    other = Bar

class Bar(object):
    other = Foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'all ok'
```

?

The problem seems to be that since the property is on the class, since it tries to executes as soon as the class itself is parsed.

Is there a way to solve that?

*edit:*

those keys are used for SQLAlchemy mapping, to they realy are class variables (not instance).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would do what you want:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

class Bar(object):
    pass

Foo.other = Bar
Bar.other = Foo
```

I would prefer to avoid such design completely, though.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds... :-)

Comment: This is used with sqlalchemy to create relations between models, the doc seems to point to such a design (the doc for flask to be precise), that solution seems a weird.

Comment: AFAIK sqlalchemy uses string references for foreign keys and avoids this problem that way, but maybe there are some cases where you need to do this.

Comment: @sharvey: That is important information that belongs in the question. Most ORMs have a proper way to resolve such a situation, but we can't tell you that if we don't know that it's what you need.

Comment: Yeah but I wanted to see if there was a solution to the more general problem first, before settling for a sqlachemy specific solution.

Comment: In virtually all the real-world use cases where you will encounter circular references (e.g., ORM, garbage collection, factory boy) this is not the way to go.  The actual attributes will likely be descriptors and metaclasses may be involved, and the framework will usually provide a declarative way to handle the situation.  –1 for being "not useful", though technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really want `Foo.other` and `Bar.other` to be class properties, rather than instance properties, then this works (I tested, just to be sure) :

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

class Bar(object):
    pass

Foo.other = Bar
Bar.other = Foo
```

If it's instance properties that you're after, then aaronasterling's answer is more appropriate.