# Python and Circular imports yet again

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

Say I have a module looking like this:

```
circlejerking/
├── bar.py
├── foo.py
└── __init__.py
```

bar.py:

```
from .foo import Foo

class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

foo.py:

```
from .bar import Bar

class Foo(object):
    my_bar = Bar()
```

`__init__.py:`

```
from .foo import Foo
from .bar import Bar

__all__ = [
    'Foo',
    'Bar'
]
```

Using that module fails because of the circular import.

```
In [1]: from circlejerking import Foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2258014c7099> in <module>()
----> 1 from circlejerking import Foo

/home/me/circlejerking/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .foo import Foo
2 from .bar import Bar
3
4 __all__ = [
5 'Foo',

/home/me/circlejerking/foo.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .bar import Bar
2
3 class Foo(object):
4 my_bar = Bar()

/home/me/circlejerking/bar.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .foo import Foo
2
3 class Bar(Foo):
4 pass

ImportError: cannot import name Foo
```

I understand the Problem and I am aware, that python related circular import problems have been discussed multiple times, but I can't seem to get this to work.
The two goto answers SO has for this problem are:

1. Redesign your code, you are holding it wrong or
2. Import the other module only where you need it.

I am fairly certain, my design is okay and yes, I am sure those two classes are not in fact one thing.

Importing the other Class somewhere else is not an option, because I need them right where they are.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps move all your imports to the `__init__`? That way your import order is resolved once and for all

Comment: Is that supposed to be `class Bar(Foo)`?  Right now you have nothing called `Bar` at all.  Also, why do you "need" it that way?

Comment: Your problem is worse than circular imports; your classes actually have circular *references*, which can't really be resolved in Python, even if both are defined in the same file.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270045/python-circular-references).  Are you sure you need `my_bar` to be a class attribute and not an instance attribute?

Comment: @BrenBarn Hm.. you are probably right and I actually wanted an instance attribute and was just stuck on the idea. Let me check.

Comment: @BrenBarn Okay, my example is just bad, I should build one that actually describes my problem.. In my actual project my_bar is a ForeignKey in the django orm. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/ I can migrate the database, putting all my attributes in a __init__ method, but I am not sure if the code would actually work that way yet.

Comment: In that case you may want [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978503/how-to-have-two-models-reference-each-other-django).

Comment: If I interpret a class as a unit of things that belong together I would argue that if two of your classes need eachother so much, it must be so important that their unit belongs into an own class. So I would go for 1. redesign your code.

Answer (score 1):

In general you could solve this with an injection pattern:

This module is fine as-is:

```
from .foo import Foo
class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

Then you other module becomes:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = None

    @classmethod
    def set_bar(cls, bar):
        cls.bar = bar
```

It's then up to whatever uses Foo to ensure that set_bar is called appropriately before you use it.